# Firebase: Push Data If Not Filled In

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm pushing some data to my Firebase, like so:

**main.js**

```
$scope.createService = function() {
  var newService = {
    title: $scope.title,
    ...
  };
  var promise = ServiceService.add(newService);
};
```

When nothing is entered in the `ng-model="title"` input field, I get an error back from the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

Is there a way to override this, and push the item to Firebase without `title` being defined?

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's not enough code here to tell what's going on. Where is Firebase in the picture? What does ServiceService.add do? (and why is it named so redundantlyreduntant?). Also, why exactly are we storing empty values in Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to set title as empty (or default value) if there's no data in ng-model="title"

```
var newService = {
    title: $scope.title || ' ',
    ...
  };
```